# Input box that accepts only a certain email domain and button that acts as submit and email domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, python-2.7

I realize the title is long and confusing, so let me clarify. I'm trying to create a sign up input form where the user signs up with their email. But I'm only accepting emails with a certain domain, for example "blah@abc.com"

I would like to create an input form that allows the user to type in the unique portion of their email ("blah") and create a button that acts as a submit button and adding the "@abc.com" portion of the email. When the user finishes typing, they can hover over that button (button:hover) and only then does it turn into a clickable button.

In short, the user doesn't have to input the @whatever.com part of the email.

I'm relatively new to programming/web dev and I know this task will involve some Python/Javascript. If you have the time, let me in on the details as to how this can be accomplished. Thanks in advance!

What I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello World">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<style type="text/css">

html {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
body {
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: #990100;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}
.btn-default {
    font-family: DecoType Naskh;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
#header {
    background:transparent;
    padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
}

#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
.content {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.jumbotron {
    background: transparent;
}
.form-group {

    height: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    position:absolute;
    background:transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.credit p {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: DecoType Naskh;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color: pink;
    border-radius: 10px;
} 

</style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="nav">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="wrapper">

                            </div>
                        </div>


                                    <a href="about.html"><button type="link1" class="btn btn-default pull-right">About</button></a>
                                    <a href="contact.html"><button type="link2" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Contact</button></a>


                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputFeedback" placeholder="If you have genuine feedbacks to improve this website, enter it here..." style="width:auto">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="credit">
                    <p></p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>


    </script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript will be your best bet here since it's the only one of those two that runs in the browser. I suggest you learn the basics of Javascript then move forward from there.

Comment: I know a bit of python, would python work? I know a bit of python already. But as for the look of the input bar, I'd need HTML/CSS for it won't I? Python for the function.

Comment: You can't run Python inside of a browser. There are ways of compiling Python into Javascript but ultimately you have to use JS to do anything dynamic. You would still need your HTML/CSS like you have above for displaying elements on a page but JS is the only thing that can dynamically change those elements for you.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Codecademy has a python course and a Javascript course. I've finished Python. Do you recommend starting javascript?